# What is SP2013 optimal environment setup?

Tags: 2013, setup, environment

Will put up a SharePoint 2013 in a Vmware environment.
Will have 8000 + users when everything is completed.
Boss wants it on Windows 2008 R2 and Sql 2008 R2.
Personally, I would prefer Windows Server 2012 and Sql 2012 R2
Costs is not a issue.
Am I on the wrong track? If not, are there any good argument for my proposal?

Comment: Hi!
Take a look at this Answers. Maybe you find them suitable.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61226/environment-setting-development-tools-for-my-sharepoint-2013-project/61228#61228